# How to confirm/disprove a hypothesis

Tags: statistics

I have a list of quadruples in the following form

```
(name, smokes, mother-smokes, father-smokes)
(Andrew, Y, N, Y)
(Jessica, N, N, N)
...
```

and I would need to confirm (or disprove) that the probability that a child will become a regular smoker depends on whether its parents are regular smokers or not. I.e. that it is more likely for a child to be a smoker when at least one of its parents are.

What technique do I use in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Hypothesis testing.
Since what we need to prove/disprove is a Boolean (smoking/not smoking), we will use Bernoulli Random Variable.

First thing you need to do is to define the Confidence Interval, let's say you declare 95% Confident Interval.

The next step is to split your quadruples into two sets, the first set is those quadruple which neither of parents do not smoke, the second set is the vice versa.

The next step is to define the null Hypothesis. You stated that you want to proof it is more likely for a child to be a smoker when at least one of it's parents are.

So the Null Hypothesis is going to be

$$
H_{0} = p_{smoking} \geq p_{non\_smoking}
$$

And also the alpha Hypothesis (opposed to Null Hypothesis)

$$
H_{\alpha} = p_{smoking} \lt p_{non\_smoking}
$$

The next step is to define the area of rejection. In this case, since we define the Confidence Interval to be 95%, using one-side Hypothesis Testing here, then we use $z_{\alpha} = -1.64$

Next you should count the $p_{non\_smoking}$ . That is, the proportion of quadruple in the first-set which smokes, the number of all quadruples in the set of smoking parents, and the number of quadruples in the set of smoking parents which smokes. I define those two numbers as $X$ and $n_{smoking}$. The last step is to compute $Z_{0}$ using this equation

$$
Z_{0} = \frac{X-n_{smoking}\cdotp p_{non\_smoking} }{ \sqrt{n_{smoking}\cdotp p_{non\_smoking} \cdotp (1-p_{non\_smoking})}}
$$

If the $Z_{0}$ is less than -1.64 then the null Hypothesis is rejected i.e. our assumption that it is more likely for a child to be a smoker when at least one of it's parents are doesn't hold.